# Edit History on Database using Spring

Tags: spring

I would like to know if a framework or a component (or even a Spring project!) exists that would allow me to save the history (automatically, or via @Java tags) of all edits done on a specific model object within my Spring project.

Thanks in advance,
Sammy

Comment: would you pls clarify your question? :)

Comment: What you mean by tags is called annotations ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a tool for auditing like Hibernate Envers. It works like a revision system for your DB entities.

Hibernate's integration with Spring is pretty straight forward, as well.

See also:

- [Hibernate Envers Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html)